# RestKit RKRelationshipMapping doesn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Here is my JSON

```
{
    "pages": 8,
    "salads": [
        {
            "id": "392",
            "img": "http://salatiki.com.ua/images/mini/20120114_285.jpg",
            "ingredCount": 5,
            "ingredients": "картофель, свекла, салат, яйцо, сливки",
            "name": "Шведский картофельный",
            "rating": 4
        },
.......
     ]
}
```

**I got "pages", but my "salads" is nil (see log).**

My NSManagedObjects

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class SSaladsBody;

@interface SSaladPage : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sPages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SSaladsBody *salads;

@end
```

for key "salads"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface SSaladsBody : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sRating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sIngredients;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sIngredientsCount;

@end
```

in my add delegate

```
RKEntityMapping *saladPageMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([SSaladPage class]) inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[saladPageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"pages" : @"sPages", }];
saladPageMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"sPages"];

RKEntityMapping *saladsBodyMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([SSaladsBody class]) inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[saladsBodyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id" : @"sId",
                                                     @"img" : @"sImage",
                                                     @"name" : @"sName",
                                                     @"rating" : @"sRating",
                                                     @"ingredients" : @"sIngredients",
                                                     @"ingredCount" : @"sIngredientsCount" }];
saladsBodyMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"sId"];

[saladPageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"salads"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"salads"
                                                                             withMapping:saladsBodyMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *saladPageDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:saladPageMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray: @[saladPageDescriptor]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"api/get.php?getByCat=1&page=1" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Mapping salads OK! %@", mappingResult.array);
}  failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}];
```

and log

```
2014-11-04 23:57:49.641 Salatiki[10213:f03] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:250 GET 'http://salatiki.com.ua/api/get.php?getByCat=1&page=1' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.0989s mapping=0.0117s total=0.1613s]
2014-11-04 23:57:49.641 Salatiki[10213:607] Mapping salads OK! (
    "<SSaladPage: 0x7b03b970> (entity: SSaladPage; id: 0x7b267d90 <x-coredata://8CC2FD2A-9D05-4863-99AA-30B318EEC57C/SSaladPage/p42> ; data: {\n    sPages = 8;\n    salads = nil;\n})"
)
```

what i'm doing wrong? I try to add one more responseDeskriptor, for "salads" it work's but he put array in to main {}; not to "salads" = []; Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SSaladsBody *salads;
```

should actually be a relationship, so it should be `NSSet`, not `SSaladsBody`.

Other than that, things look ok. If you still have issues you should turn on trace logging and see what processing is done around the relationship contents.

Comment: i don't know if i make right changes, now i get [SIGABRT](http://i.piccy.info/i9/e1302fd66326bd202050ff6943c89add/1415196377/530901/824231/Snymok_ekrana_2014_11_05_v_16_00_42.png)

Comment: Did you create a relationship, to-many, in the data model and regenerate the managed object subclasses? What does the trace logging say before it breaks?

Comment: now i get data: {\n    sPages = 8;\n    salads = \"<relationship fault: 0x78e8abf0 'salads'>\";\n})

Comment: it's funny but trace log says that everything maps perfectly... but mappingResult.array in my request said "salads = \"<relationship fault: 0x78e8abf0 'salads'>\";\n})"

Comment: `<relationship fault: 0x78e8abf0 'salads'>` just means that the objects aren't loaded into memory so you can't tell exactly what's there. For test purposes you can add a loop which iterates the relationship contents and logs each object separately.

Comment: So is it normal that i have such log? here is my [Model](http://i.piccy.info/i9/306148e101a0244add9049c5fc2f5a35/1415269017/39041/824231/Snymok_ekrana_2014_11_06_v_12_16_33.png) Can you please add to you post some example code about loop which iterates the relationship contents and logs each object separately, i'm new in Core Data ind i don't know what exactly to log. Thank you.

Comment: You should make all of the relationships bi-directional (always in Core Data). Just a for loop and `NSLog(@"%@", object);` for each item.

Comment: Thank you very much! I make all relationships bi-directional and now i see in my "salads" core data objects, i hope it's normal view for them `"salads =     (\n        \"0x78fe5a60 <x-coredata://D64DB7E5-3EB7-49A9-ABEB-64CDBB64AF33/SSaladsBody/p10>\",\n"`

Comment: now my customer say that i don't need to cache "salads" how can i load them after request? just save result to dictionary or i need to use NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: I don't understand the follow up question - consider creating a new question specifically for that with a full explanation